# How to mock ResultSet.next() method using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am mocking `java.sql.ResultSet` like this

```
ResultSet rs = mock(ResultSet.class);
when(rs.next()).thenReturn(true); // this seems wrong appraoch
```

Test code is like this

```
while (rs.next()) {
  // doing stuff here
}
```

So problem is when I have mock `rs.next()` to `true` then `while` loop never terminates. I want to terminate `while` loop after 2 iteration. So how i can mock `rs.next()` method?

I have also tried

```
when(rs.next()).thenReturn(true, true, false); // always return false
```

Please help!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can chain `doReturn()` method calls:

```
doReturn(true).doReturn(true).doReturn(false).when(rs).next();
```

Or, as mentioned in the comments, chain `thenReturn` method calls:

```
when(rs.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
```

Or, if you want to take things even further, you can use Mockito `Answer`s:

```
when(rs.next()).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
    private int iterations = 2;

    Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        return iterations-- > 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: You can also chain thenReturn: when(rs.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false)

Comment: Your both approaches are behaving same as  : when(rs.next()).thenReturn(true, true, false); which is not working case :(

Comment: it always takes last value as a resultant thenReturn ?

Comment: Just tested locally using Mockito 1.10.19. My code works as expected.

Comment: ok, your code technically looks fine to me as well but I was telling some how may be i am missing something and can't figure out :(

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
when(rs.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
```

Comment: i am getting false on rs.next() every time :( not worked

Comment: Works for me with Mockito 2.0.2 beta. If you're still stuck, maybe you should edit your question to append the full test with your attempted fixes, and mention the version of Mockito in case someone knows about a bug.

Comment: I have used your approach in a different test it works fine but in this specific scenario it doesn't. I guess i am missing something! dont know what :(

Answer (score 0):

While other answers are technically correct (*if doesn't work in your code then maybe something else is in play and more code is needed*). They all miss a vital point:

You should not mock JDBC classes but instead create an integration test with a real database behind. Also beware `ResultSet` is indeed an interface but drivers / DB may have some differences in behavior. Such test that are mocking those, makes developers blind to real production behaviors.

And if this code is just about handling data that is returned not the actual JDBC invocation code, then this code should be decoupled of JDBC classes in that `ResultSet` should not be imported. In the long run it helps to split technical code from business code.

Comment: hmm, i think u r right . I have used MockResultSet of mockrunner lib. its works fine but i cant do other major things with that.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with the need for integration tests, but saying that you **only** need integration tests for cases like this is a bridge too far. It is completely possible that lower-level DAO-type code is expected to behave differently in case a different number of results is returned (e.g. throw an exception if multiple records are returned). Testing that behavior using a unit test makes complete sense.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes of course there's always some good reason to not follow such guidelines, but this is usually very narrow cases ; this doesn't appear to be one here. Anyway, even for the case you mention, implementors or different versions may fail differently and in unexpected ways, depending on the proper conditions. Testing such conditions may prove really challenging, additional mocking here with a DB behind may give a false sense of security. External systems are much more tricky to test correctly and securely than we use to think, and mocking is rarely if at all part of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
when(rs.next()).thenReturn(true, true, false);
```

this should work.

i find an example from the javadoc of 'mockito-core:1.10.19'.

take a look at this:
[org.mockito.Mockito.when](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKAL8.png)